# How to instantiate a class properly?

Tags: c++, atl

I'm trying to implement into ATL :

```
std::list<CMyClass> listMC;
CMyClass lmc;
listMC.insert(listMC.end(), lmc);
```

How do I instantiate `lmc` which is an ATL class which was created using `Class View > New > Class` ?

I'm actually getting errors on `lmc` :

```
Error: object of abstract class type "CProcessusModel" is not allowed :
function "CProcessusModel::AddRef" is a virtual function 
function "CProcessusModel::Release" is a virtual function  
function "CProcessusModel::QueryInterface" is a virtual function
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Don't use `new` in the first place.

Comment: @chris, sorry for that, I haven't that into my code.

Comment: show us the start of the CProcessusModel class declaration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your error messages, the class `CProcessusModel` is abstract. You cannot instantiate abstract classes.

To make your class concrete, you have to

A) Implement the virtual functions that are listed in the error message in the class `CProcessusModel` or

B) derive a concrete subclass from the abstract `CProcessusModel`, which implements all pure virtual methods and instantiate objects of that type.

Comment: Do I need to simply implement `CMyClass::get__NewEnum(IUnknown** xx);` ?

Comment: If that function is pure virtual in one of `CMyClass` parents, then yes, you must implement it in order for `CMyClass` to be a concrete class. Along with any other pure virtual methods.